# upload only pdf and docx file with springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, file-upload

I have a method that upload files, i want to accept just (pdf) and (docx) files, how i can do that.
this is the method :

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile (@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
    String message = "";
    try {
        
      
        fileService.store(file);
  
      message = "Uploaded the file successfully: " + file.getOriginalFilename();
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      message = "Could not upload the file: " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set allowed content type for endpoint:
`@PostMapping("/upload", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE, "application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"})`

Or you can validate file extension from input.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is to validate file extension from input as suggested by @Kryszak.
Simply add one if condition to allow pdf and docx.
For Example :

```
if (StringUtils.endsWithIgnoreCase(fileName, "pdf") || StringUtils.endsWithIgnoreCase(fileName, "docx")){
 //process file
}
else{
 // show message to user, only accept pdf & docx files.
}
```

Comment: i have angular in frontend, the input is : ` <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)" />` , i don't know how i can implement your idea here.

Comment: I find the solution in my case the frontend is angular the input should be :  `<input type="file" accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" (change)="selectFile($event)" />`